# Какой знак препинания поставить перед словом "это"?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания поставить перед словом "это" в предложении:

> Попробуй это вкусно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны два варианта членения предложения:

(1) *Попробуй, это вкусно!*   ЭТО — подлежащее во втором предложении.

(2) *Попробуй это,  вкусно!*  ЭТО — дополнение в первом предложении.

В обоих случаях это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП). Во втором варианте вместо запятой можно использовать тире, если нужно подчеркнуть паузу.

Comment: Почему бы не поставить запятую и тире? Попробуй, - это вкусно!